# How to debug s3 notifications

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, notifications, amazon-sqs

I'm facing a sporadic issue with s3 notifications.
There is s3 notification config applied to bucket for the following actions:

```
'Events': ['s3:ObjectCreated:*'],
```

Prefix:

```
DP/event-triggering-export-data-test/
```

Suffix:

```
.json.gpg
```

Notification are configured with SQS as events consumer.
One time I'm successfully receiving an event on putting file with the extension above, another not on the same action.

I'm looking toward `CloudTrails`.
But seems it doesn't support logging of object level actions like `s3:ObjectCreated`.

So, what is the proper way to debug the case?

Comment: I had similar issue. KMS-CMK attached to SNS for encryption was to blame.